# Tie DIV element to overflow scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a datagrid table that will allow me to fix the header. I have placed the table within two DIV elements and fixed the THEAD portion of the table. I populate the table dynamically and there can be a different number of columns and may have different widths each time.

```
<DIV style="position: relative; width="500px">
 <DIV style="height:105px; overflow: auto;">
  <TABLE width="502px">
    <THEAD>
      <TR style="left:-1px;top: 0;position: absolute;">
        ... header content ...
      </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
      ... data columns ...
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
 </DIV>
</DIV>
```

The solution works well for the vertical overflow.  However, I'm struggling with the horizontal overflow.  Because I fixed the THEADs TR element, if my table exceeds the DIV width, the horizontal scrollbar appears and I can scroll the data horizontally, but the titles are static and don't scroll.

I was thinking that I might be able to somehow scroll the table header using jQuery if I could get the id/name of the dynamically created scrollbar, but I don't know if this is the right solution or if it is even possible.

Comment: there is no need to use jQuery, you can use css `position: fixed`.

Comment: Sorry I had to update the question ( I mixed up my verticals and horizontals originally)

Comment: @Raminson - I tried the `position:fixed` suggestion but that didn't work (it may be because it was a response to the earlier question with vertical/horizontal reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ton of people have tried to make fixed headers and left columns for tables using html and css, that stay put while you scroll, and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Your only option is to use javascript to manipulate the table as it scrolls. I have no specific code to recommend, but do some google searches.

Comment: Staying put seemed to be the easy part thanks to the solution I found [here](http://pics.cssbakery.com/treats/scrollingtable/tableTest6.php). It's the horizontal scrolling and moving the header TR that's the issue for me.

Comment: @NEW2WEB I know. Like I said - it can't be done in pure HTML/CSS. If you want it, you need to also use javascript.

Comment: thanks, but that's what I'm looking for, I don't need it to be pure CSS/HTML. So do you have any examples?

Comment: @NEW2WEB I used `jquery floatheader` once. Mainly because it was the first link on google that did what I needed. There are plenty of others, with features like sorting and rearranging columns available.